# firefox sdk append html file

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I append html to a tab of firefox from my script with the following code:

`main.js`:

```
let worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [
      data.url("jquery.min.js"),
      data.url("worker.js")
    ],
    contentScriptOptions: contentOptions
  });
  attach(style, tabs.activeTab);
```

`worker.js`:

```
$('body').append("<div>foo</div>");
```

My question is:
Is it posible to have the html code to an html file and append the file. This will make the code more beatiful and readable.

## EDIT:

if the previous code submited to mozilla full review, it will be rejected, because creates DOM nodes from HTML strings containing potentially unsanitized data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use [`data.load(name)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data.load%28name%29) and send the HTML contents to your contentScript:

**main.js**

```
let worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [
      data.url("jquery.min.js"),
      data.url("worker.js")
    ],
    contentScriptOptions: contentOptions
  });
worker.port.emit("html", data.load("worker.html"));
```

**worker.js**

```
self.port.on('html', function(contents) {
  $('body').append(contents);
});
```

**worker.html**

```
<div>foo</div>
```

Comment: it''s a good answer but is it any other way? I have a lot of different of html tags and the code will be complicated if I use the ports.

Comment: I don't know of any, sorry.